# Substitution of one type by another

Tags: c, xml, sml

When we perform substitution, can one type substitute another type?
This is too broad a question because it concerns general concepts of programming rather than specific programming language.

Thank You.

Comment: So, uh, if you state in the question that it is "too broad", then maybe it's not worth asking it at all?

Comment: I was not expecting -2 but here we go, but its about abstract data type in programming. can one variable of a certain Sort replace another variable of another Sort? I wrote above post to generalize it into simple language so that I can get many answers to conclude from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitution of one type for another is purely dependent on your requirement.
You can also `typedef` the given type or you can make your own type.
You can perform type substitution using `template` also 
Btw your question is little incomplete to give accurate answer , what exactly you want to ask?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error : see this

Comment: your answer was helpful. Thanks